SpellingSuggestion always null
Generally, I've seen a degradation of Microsoft SharePoint related classic service features, in the sense that functionality is being silently withdrawn.
Recently, probably in the last few months, the SpellingSuggestion property started returning always null when calling _api/search/postquery.
This is the value which was displayed in the "Did you mean [spellingSuggestion]?".
Anyone knows how to get the spelling suggestion for a query search term programmatically these days?
I've been digging into PnP modern search web requests but since it's using the same endpoint, the result is the same.
Also, I've noticed that on the modern UI search page (_layouts/15/search.aspx), the following URL is used:
https://outlook.office365.com/search/api/v2/query
I couldn't find any documentation at all about this URL, probably it's intended to be used internally by Microsoft.
